# How do I connect my laptop (VGA port) to a TV (HDMI port only)

Tags: laptop, hdmi, vga, tv, cable

I have a laptop which has a VGA port only. I want to connect it to a TV which has a HDMI port only. As expected, the TV has a HDMI cable only.

So, what would be the simplest way to connect my laptop and the TV?

PS: I am concerned only about the video and not the audio.

Comment: Your TV does not have DVI?

Answer (score 0):

You will need a VGA to HDMI converter.  Most devices of this type require that your PC be set to a resolution that the TV can handle natively.

Comment: Note that these are fairly expensive as VGA is an analog signal, and HDMI is digital, so it is more than just a simple presentation conversion, it is an active device.  You could get a media player for a similar cost.

Answer (score 0):

you can't directly connect. so you need VGA to HDMI Adapter.